# Logic Problem between Main Class and Thread Class

Tags: java, android

Hy!!

I make a new `Object` from a `Thread` Class. There is a Http-Post in the run method with a result string.

My Question:

How is it possible to notify the main class that the download finished?

MFG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class which helps you handling work on another thread than the UI thread. It's a very useful class of the Android framework.

You simply create a custom class which inherits from AsyncTask and then you override the [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) and insert the code that should be executed in its own thread. In your case this would be the code to do the download. Furthermore you have to override the [`onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) which is called automatically when the doInBackground() method has finished. The object you returned in the doInBackground() method will be automatically passed to the onPostExecute() method. The onPostExecute() will be execute on the UI thread.

So the AsyncTask class will handle all the thread stuff for you and you can focus on your work.

Have a look at the [tutorial on the Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Answer (score 1):

If by "main class" you mean your `Activity` then you can use a `Handler`.

In your activity:

```
private static final int DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE = 0;
...

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
        case DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE:
            Log.d("MYTAG",msg.obj.toString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And in some other class:

```
public doBackgroundUpdate(Handler handler){
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do long-running post operation

            // send result back to UI thread
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE;
            msg.obj = "Result String to pass";
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    backgroundThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a thread, create a [`Callable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and pass it to an [`ExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) by way of the `submit()` method:

```
Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)
```

Submitting a `Callable` object to the `ExecutorService` returns a `Future` object. The `get()` method of `Future` will then block until the task has completed and will contain the results of the `Callable`.

Example:

```
    Callable<String> callable = new Callable<String>(){
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return "HELLO WORLD";
        }
    };

    //executor with one thread
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);
    executor.shutdown();
    String result = future.get();
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks... but how to make it in two classes ?  implement Callable <bool>. How to get access from the main class?